# Is there an upper limit on the coordination number of a coordination compound?

Tags: coordination-compounds

From the [Gold Book](https://goldbook.iupac.org/html/C/C01331.html), coordination number is:

> In an inorganic coordination entity, the number of σ-bonds between ligands and the central atom. π-bonds are not considered in determining the coordination number.

In high school, we mostly had complexes upto coordination number six (like $\ce{[FeF6]^3-}$). But I wondered if the coordination number could go even higher.

From my search, I was able to reach [this research paper](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja00496a010?journalCode=jacsat) (*J. Am. Chem. Soc.*, **1979**, *101* (2), pp 334–340 DOI: 10.1021/ja00496a010) where they mention lanthanide complexes of coordination number uptil **nine**!

So, is **nine** the upper limit? Or can the coordination number go higher? Also, does the upper limit exist only *theoretically*, or has the corresponding complex been synthesized?

Comment: Theoretically speaking, coordination number is not a thing at all, especially when we look at lanthanides with their ugly coordination polyhedra. The maximum possible coordination number is not a physical constant of any significance. Practically speaking, I vaguely remember hearing of CN up to 14 in uranium borohydrides or something.

Comment: See [Can an atom bond with more than 8 other atoms?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/31950/can-an-atom-bond-with-more-than-8-other-atoms/31961#31961)

Comment: Note: I self-marked the question as duplicate after having two CVs and then going through the linked question. The thing is - even if the titles do not match - the excellent, well-detailed answers to that question contain exactly the stuff I am looking for, and it makes little sense to report them over here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see why not. It is a matter of having

- enough of an interaction between the center and the ligands, usually in the form of donor/acceptor orbital pairs, and
- enough space around the coordination center.

These go hand-in-hand, as any atom that will have enough electrons to donate to ligands will also most likely have a larger atomic radius than a first-row transition metal like iron.

For example, here is a thorium complex that has CN = 15 in its crystal structure and CN = 16 in an isolated gas-phase density functional calculation:

[image: structure of [Th(H3BNMe2BH3)4]]

[Daly, Scott R.; Piccoli, Paula M. B.; Schultz, Arthur J.; Todorova, Tanya K.; Gagliardi, Laura; Girolami, Gregory S. Synthesis and Properties of a Fifteen-Coordinate Complex: The Thorium Aminodiboronate $\ce{[Th(H3BNMe2BH3)4]}$. *Angew. Chem. Int. Ed.* **2010**, *49*, 3379-3381, DOI: 10.1002/anie.200905797](https://dx.doi.org/10.1002/anie.200905797)

Comment: Hmm, thanks! A small query though, "any atom that will have enough electrons to donate to ligands" isn't it in the other direction? Ligands donate electrons to metals, and not vice-versa? (pardon my basic knowledge, but that's what I was taught)

Comment: See [metal-to-ligand charge transfer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge-transfer_complex#Metal-to-ligand_charge_transfer).