# How does a molecule (for example, ClF₅) have a steric number of more than 4 if SP³ hybridisation is the maximum?

Tags: hybridization

> "The sum of the number of atoms bonded to a central atom and the number of lone pairs formed by its nonbonding valence electrons is known as the central atom's steric number."
>
> [Wikipedia's entry about "Steric number"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steric_number)

I just started learning hybridisation and stuff for fun, and I just found out this "oddity".

Comment: [This](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/19433/how-can-iodine-bond-with-5-fluorines-in-iodine-pentafluoride/19437#19437) earlier answer relating to $\ce{IF5}$ may be helpful.

Answer (score -4):

The steric number of $\ce{ClF_5}$ is 6, and this is possible because $\ce{sp^3}$ hybridization is not the maximum, or the 'limit' to hybridization. In the case of $\ce{ClF_5}$ the hybridization is $\ce{sp^3d^2}$, the hybridization involving  the $\ce{3s}$,  $\ce{3p}$ and  $\ce{3d}$ orbitals.

[image: MOT]

Image credits: https://techiescientist.com/clf5-lewis-structure/

Comment: 3d orbitals are not involved in bonding in ClF5. The best representation is partial covalent bonds (ie bond order <1) combined with ionic interactions.

Comment: Supporting @Andrew see https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/4760/why-do-compounds-like-sf6-and-sf4-exist-but-sh6-and-sh4-dont/49844#49844

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/76726/4945